# Deprecated feature 'Table hint without WITH' is not supported on SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

When I am trying to export-data- tier application from SQL database I am getting issue in stored procedure:

> error :Deprecated feature 'Table hint without WITH' is not supported on SQL Azure

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory... You probably have something like `SELECT * FROM Table (NOLOCK)`, as the message indicates you must use the word `WITH` --- `SELECT * FROM Table WITH (NOLOCK)`.

Comment: As a general rule, when posting on Stackoverflow it is a good idea to actually ask a question. In addition, if you are getting an error, it is probably advisable to post the code that is causing the error. IN the absence of these two things people are going to have to guess what your question is, and what is causing the error, then guess at a solution. All of which is not going to be as helpful as if you posted a proper question with full details.

Comment: that isnot table it is a stord procedure

Comment: I know, but a stored procedure contains SQL, and if you check the stored procedure definition you will probably see a table hint used without `WITH`. e.g `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProc AS SELECT * FROM Table (NOLOCK);`

Answer (score 1):

Agree with GarethD, you can try to add With(NOLOCK). The feature has been deprecated in [SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx)